# Firestore security rule strange behaviour

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestore security rule the following line works for the read operation to find the **request.auth.uid** in an array of integers **resource.data.uids**:

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.uids;
```

But the above line doesn't work for the update operation. I had to cast the **request.auth.uid** to an integer to make it work for the update operation as follows:

```
allow update: if int(request.auth.uid) in resource.data.uids;
```

I would like to know the reason behind this strange behaviour.

Comment: `request.auth.uid` isn't an integer.  It's a string generated by Firebase Authentication for uniquely identifying a user account.  It should never be cast to an integer, and it doesn't make sense to compare it to other integers.  Why are you trying to do so?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson. In my case `request.auth.uid` contains a numerical string value and `resource.data.uids` contains an array of integers. This means I will have to cast `request.auth.uid` to an integer for the comparsion to match with `resource.data.uids` which contains integers . If `resource.data.uids` was an array of numerical strings then casting `request.auth.uid` to an integer wouldn't have been necessary

Answer (score 0):

After changing the data type of the `uid` used in `.where("uids", "array-contains", uid)` to an integer both the read and update operations now work with the following line:

```
allow read, update: if int(request.auth.uid) in resource.data.uids;
```

Things now look normal because `resource.data.uids` contains an array of integers and `request.auth.uid` contains a numerical string value which has to be cast to an integer for the comparison to match.